# Hide and Expand UITableView Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement a feature where if a user clicks on one of the items in my `UICollectionView` (that is embedded within a `UITableViewCell`) it causes another section to appear in the `UITableView` (below the `UICollectionView`) with information about that item. I'm having problems with the height of the section that is to appear when clicked. If I set it to 0 initially in heightForRowAtIndexPath there doesn't seem to be a way to alter the cells height later on. I tried giving the cell an initial height then hiding it with `cell.hidden` but that still leaves the section visible. Maybe there is an alternative way to do this, but after a lot of googling i'm coming up short.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 3  {
        return 90
    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return 185
    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        return 155
    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 4 {
        return 100
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("weeklyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WxTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.forecastCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.forecastCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.forecastCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell.forecastCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.forecastCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return cell
    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 4 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dailyInformation", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WxTableViewCell
        cell.hidden = true
        cell.contentView.hidden = true
        return cell
    }
    ...
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)
    let myindex = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 4)
    var myTable = self.tableView
    var lastCell = myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)
    var dailyCell = myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(myindex)
    var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, lastCell!.frame.width, lastCell!.frame.height))
    dailyCell.frame.size = myView.frame.size
}
```

Comment: You should avoid trying to alter cells from other cells. Simply have an action in one cell update your data model and then reload the sections which may be affected. Assuming you have your code right for cell creation and returning the height, they will look after themselves. So process should be: cell or item in cell is clicked -> Update data model -> reload affected sections or rows or whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use indexPath numbers directly to address cells and sections in a switch/case. It's hard to handle when you want add/remove a row/section in the middle. Instead create an enum which have all sections and use an array that contains sections to be shown. You can have cell or section properties like cell identifiers or height in that enum.

```
enum FileDetailsCell: Printable {
    case FileName, Location, Size

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .FileName: return "noname"
        case .Location: return"Location"
        case .Size: return "Size"
        }
    }

    var defaultValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .Location: return "/"
        case .Size: return "Unknown"
        default: return ""
        }
    }

    var cellIdentifier: String {
        switch self {
        case .FileName: return "fileNameCell"
        default: return "detailCell"
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use description for Cell title. defaultValue for initial value of cell and cellIdentifier is obvious for which purpose.

Then define an array which contains active cells:

```
var cellsArray: [FileDetailsCell] = [.FileName, .Size]
```

you can modify this array when you want change visible cells. Now, Location cell is hidden but you can make it visible later only by appending ".Location" to this array and reload tableView.

For tableview delegate:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellsArray.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellInfo = cellsArray[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellInfo.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    switch cellInfo {
        case .FileName:
            cell.textLabel?.text = item.fileName;
        case .Location:
            cell.textLabel?.text = cellInfo.description
            cell.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = item.locationFormatted ?? cellInfo.defaultValue;
        case .Size:
            cell.textLabel?.text = cellInfo.description
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = item.size ?? cellInfo.defaultValue;
    }

    return cell
}
```

In this example I assumed sections are only one to avoid confusion. You can get similar approach for sections.